# iPhone: Group by month - Core Data

Tags: iphone

I store dates in a core data entity
attribute, I then display the date in
the table cells. I want to group all
the cells according to months and only
display the relevant dates in the
correct sections.

I'm using sectionNameKeyPath of the
NSFetchedResultsController, but I need
to only use the month in the date to
group. How can I achieve this? Would I
need to create a new attribute and
store just the month as a string or
can I use NSPredicate?

Please can anyone let me know if they
have done this or give me some
examples.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Step one, make sure you have a Managed Object Class in your project that represents the core data entity that stores the date.  Step two, in the implementation file for this entity, write a method that returns the month for that object.  It should look at the date variable and use `NSDateComponents` methods to determine the month.  You need not create a new attribute for it.  Step three, when you initialize your NSFetchedResultsController, pass the name of the method that returns the month as the `sectionNameKeyPath` parameter.  What you are essentially doing is creating a "getMonth" method that programmatically determines the month, and giving the value returned by that to the sectionNameKeyPath.  I hope this is clear.  Please ask for clarification if not.

Note.  Make sure your month method returns the month in a way that sorts in the proper order (ie not alphabetically), and that your Table View translates that into a meaningful string.

Comment: You can use Sort to avoid manage the order of the months. 

 NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];

Answer (score 4):

Apple has a really great sample showing exactly how you can achieve this. I think it is what you are looking for.

Check out: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DateSectionTitles/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009939