# How to group results in an array by date in CoreData

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-data

I am fetching `X` information from `ExerciseData` `CoreData Entity` and I would like to organise it so that I can average `Y value` and orderBy day. `X` will have more than 1 result per day.

I was wondering how do I do `SELECT AVG(column_name) FROM table_name WHERE date = my_date GROUP BY column_name` in CoreData.

I will not know how far back the date will go.  Is there a "best way" to an `Array` with results being organised by date meaning. `@[ @{@"day1":@"avg_4"},@{@"day2":@"avg_88"}, ....]`

I would really appreciate some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using `NSFetchRequest` to retrieve your data? Then the [setPropertiesToGroupBy:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFetchRequest/setPropertiesToGroupBy%3a) method might help you.

Answer (score 0):

[group by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564231/iphone-group-by-month-core-data)
refer this and make sure you are using       NSManaged Objet class