# UITableView header dates using NSFetchedResultsController - Swift?

Tags: ios, uitableview, date, swift, core-data

I'm pulling string values from Core Data and displaying them in a UITableView...that's working and displaying all entries.  I now want to 'group' these values by date created (also stored in Core Data) but am having a hard time implementing this group header...here's what I have:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var sound = self.sounds[indexPath.row]
        var cell = UITableViewCell()

        // Convert Date to String
        var formatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss"
        let dateTimePrefix: String = formatter.stringFromDate(sound.dateSaved)
        // Display the following in each rows
        cell.textLabel!.text = sound.name + " Saved: " + dateTimePrefix

        return cell
    }
```

Could someone point me in the right direction as to how to implement 'headers'?  I already have the tableView in my Main.storyboard setup to 'Grouped' as a style.

--- Update

Thanks for the response below but, unfortunately, the examples are in Obj-C and I'm shooting for swift.

To expand, I have the following retrieving data from Core Data and displaying all in UITableView:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    var context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate).managedObjectContext!
    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Sound")
    self.sounds = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)! as [Sound]
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.sounds.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "MyTestCell")
    var sound = self.sounds[indexPath.row]

    // Convert Date to String
    var formatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd @ HH:mm:ss"
    let dateTimePrefix: String = formatter.stringFromDate(sound.dateSaved)
    // Display the following in each rows
    cell.textLabel!.text = sound.name // Sound Name
    // Display the following as each subtitles
    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = dateTimePrefix // Sound Duration (Currently 'date')

    return cell
}
```

Could someone point me in the right direction as to how I go about 'grouping' each by month with a 'month' header using `sectionNameKeyPath`, I believe?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `sectionNameKeyPath`, specifically with a computed section title based on the date.

[iPhone: Group by month - Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564231/iphone-group-by-month-core-data)
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DateSectionTitles/Introduction/Intro.html